# Вывод картинок поста WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Вывожу в WordPress массив с id картинок:

```
 var_dump ($gt3_theme_pagebuilder["post-formats"]["images"]);
```

Вывод:

```
array(3) { 
[78]=> array(1) { ["attach_id"]=> string(4) "1739" } 
[279]=> array(1) { ["attach_id"]=> string(4) "2457" } 
[280]=> array(1) { ["attach_id"]=> string(4) "2458" } 
}
```

Хочу вывести теперь картинки всех фото по их ID:

```
foreach ($gt3_theme_pagebuilder as $key => $foto_id) {
    wp_get_attachment_image ($foto_id);
 }
```

Этот код не работает. Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы же сами привели структуру переменной...

На входе функции `wp_get_attachment_image()` ожидается целое число, а вы передаете массив. 
Вы полагаете, что переменная `$foto_id` в вашем цикле содержит ID фото, а на самом деле там массив вида `["attach_id" => "1739"]`. Чтобы достать ID, нужно обратиться к нему по ключу `attach_id`.

Вот исправленный код:

```
$gt3_theme_pagebuilder = [
    78  => [ "attach_id" => "1739" ],
    279 => [ "attach_id" => "2457" ],
    280 => [ "attach_id" => "2458" ]
];

foreach ($gt3_theme_pagebuilder as $key => $foto) {
    wp_get_attachment_image($foto['attach_id']);
}
```

Comment: Да, спасибо, уже разобрал. Вывел нужные картинки на страницу поста, все как надо, только надо теперь сделать из них слайдер галлерею и зуум еффектом по клику, есть идеи?) Плагины готовые по типу WP lightbox 2 не работают, тут сайт на get pagebuilder и он выводит картинки нестандартно, поетому переписывать плагин, тему и т.д. У меня уже есть вывод, теперь 3 пунктика. Слайдером сделать, и зум еффект, буду пробовать.

Comment: Это уже другой вопрос. Если мой ответ вам помог, пожалуйста, проголосуйте за него и отметьте верным (галка слева от ответа).

Comment: @BonBonSlick, забыл упомянуть вас в комментарии выше. Прочитайте его, пожалуйста.

Comment: @ VenZell окей, пасиб, отметил.